# django.conf import settings vs from project.settings import VAR

Tags: django, settings

I was reading this article here about [django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/)

I understand "that django.conf.settings isn’t a module – it’s an object." That's why I can't import variables. I only need the statement CURRENCIES in my settings.

Is the right approach to do `from django.conf import settings` and then `var = settings.CURRENCIES` or can I do `from [projectname].settings import CURRENCIES`

Both is working for me. But I wonder if there is a recommended approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method `from django.conf import settings` is preferable. You may have different setting files for different environments, for instance `test_settings.py`, `dev_settings.py` and `prod_settings.py`. With `from django.conf import settings` your code will automatically give you settings using by your project at the moment.

Also second method will not provide you access to the default settings not defined in setting file.

Quote from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code):

> Also note that your code should not import from either global_settings
>   or your own settings file. django.conf.settings abstracts the concepts
>   of default settings and site-specific settings; it presents a single
>   interface. It also decouples the code that uses settings from the
>   location of your settings.

Comment: Thank you @neverwalkaloner. Your answer helped me a lot!